# Python Script adding data to Google Docs via Google Apps Scripts returning 404 : "Error: Requested entity was not found."

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to create a custom Google Doc template that will auto-populate using some data that was previously scrapped in my python script. I've managed to create the template and scrape the required data.

However when I try to send the data over to the Google Apps Scripts, I receive the following error:

> 404 : "Error: Requested entity was not found."

I believe the problem is occurring as a result of either the parameters being sent in my Python script or the function in my Google Apps Scripts. All scopes and credentials have been assigned and the ID of the script and the docs have been omitted for privacy reasons. Could anyone share some guidance as to how to fix this? It would be much appreciated

Here is my code so far...

**Google Apps Scripts**

```js
var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.openById("id of template doc").getBody();
var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById("id of final doc");
var body = targetDoc.getBody();

function scrapetoDoc(e) {
  Logger.log(e)
  var company = e.parameter.company;
  var product = e.parameter.product;
  var model = e.parameter.model;
  var date = e.parameter.date;

  copyDoc();

  body.replaceText("{{Date}}", date);
  body.replaceText("{{Company}}", company);
  body.replaceText("{{Product}}", product);
  body.replaceText("{{Model}}", model);

  targetDoc.saveAndClose();
}

function copyDoc() {
  var totalElements = sourceDoc.getNumChildren();

  for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
    var element = sourceDoc.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
      body.appendParagraph(element);
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      body.appendTable(element);
      }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      body.appendListItem(element);
      }
    }
}
```

**Main Python function**

```py
    try:
        service = build('script', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        request = {
            "function": "scrapetoDoc",
            "parameters": [{
                "company": scrapped_data[0],
                "product": scrapped_data[1],
                "model": scrapped_data[2],
                "date": scrapped_data[4]}]
        }

        # Make the API request.
        response = service.scripts().run(
            body=request,
            scriptId=SCRIPT_ID
        ).execute()

    except errors.HttpError as error:
        # The API encountered a problem.
        print(error.content)
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. When I saw your showing Google Apps Script, I thought that from the arguments, you might have wanted to request as Web Apps. On the other hand, when I saw your showing Python script, I thought that you might have wanted to request Google Apps Script API. Can I ask you about the details of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, no worries at all - What I am looking to achieve is to send some data that I scrapped using my python script to my Google Apps Script as a parameter to my function. The function will create a new document using a template I have made already and fill in the detail using the data that was passed

Comment: I am quite new to Google Apps Scripts and I am unsure whether I am achieving my goal the right way via Web Apps or API?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Which do you want to use Google Apps Script API or Web Apps for achieving your goal?

Comment: I think Google Apps Scripts API would be a suitable choice for my goal!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I think Google Apps Scripts API would be a suitable choice for my goal!`, I think that this official document might be useful. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run

Comment: @Tanaike I'm still having difficulty trying to get this to work. I've read the documentation but I still can figure this out. Would you be able to help me please?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your current issue from your reply. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike What exactly do you not understand, please tell me and I will try to explain

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `@Tanaike What exactly do you not understand, please tell me and I will try to explain`, I apologize for my poor English skill again. When I can correctly understand your current issue, I would like to try to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your current issue soon. I would like to study more.

Comment: @Tanaike Do you know if there is another solution where I can pass data from my Python script to my Google Apps Script? I really have been trying to figure this out for weeks